# the bullet in my spaceinvaders Game isnt spawning

Tags: python

Currently, I'm coding Space Invaders and encountered a bug in my Python code: I implemented a bullet, but it won't spawn when I'm pressing the space bar. I've drawn the bullet, and everything is perfectly set up. The spaceship movement works fine. I suspect there might be an issue with the update function, and PyCharm is not showing any errors. Can you help me fix that?

```
import pygame

class Game:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        pygame.init()
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height ))
        pygame.display.set_caption("space invaders")
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.running = True
        self.spaceship = Spaceship(self, 370, 515)

        self.background_img = pygame.image.load("sky.png")

        while self.running:
            self.clock.tick(60)
            self.screen.blit(self.background_img, (0, 0))
            self.spaceship.update()

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    self.running = False

                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        self.spaceship.move(-10)
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        self.spaceship.move(10)
                    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                        self.spaceship.fire_bullet()


                if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        self.spaceship.move(10)
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        self.spaceship.move(-10)

            pygame.display.update()
            if len(self.spaceship.bullets) > 0:
                for bullet in self.spaceship.bullets:
                    if bullet.is_fired == True:
                        bullet.update()



class Spaceship:
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.change_x = 0
        self.game = game
        self.spaceship_img = pygame.image.load("spaceship.png")
        self.bullets = []

    def fire_bullet(self):
        self.bullets.append(bullet(self.game, self.x, self.y))
        self.bullets[len(self.bullets) - 1].fire()


    def move(self, speed):
        self.change_x += speed


    def update(self):
        self.x += self.change_x
        self.game.screen.blit(self.spaceship_img, (self.x, self.y))
        if self.x < 0:
            self.x = 0
        elif self.x > 736:
            self.x = 736

class bullet:
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.game = game
        self.is_fired = False
        self.bullet_speed = 10
        self.bullet_img = pygame.image.load("bullet.png")


    def fire(self):
        self.is_fired = True

    def update(self):
        self.game.screen.blit(self.bullet_img, (self.x, self.y))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    game = Game(800, 600)
```

Comment: I don't see wher eyou consume the `.bullet_speed` attribute to change its  `y` attribute.

Comment: Sorry, I'm watching a tutorial, and my goal is to have the bullets spawn. The bullet speed will be addressed later in the tutorial when the bullets start moving. I apologize for not mentioning this earlier.

Comment: as a side note: if your tutorial contains the literal line `if bullet.is_fired == True:` I'd suggest looking for another tutorial already. :-)  (Sorry for the joke, but that is both redundant and incorrect code - `if` alone already tests if something is "truthy". So, just `if bullet.is_fired` would work - on the other hand, not all truthy things are "equal to " `True` itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I just run your code as is, (although you did not pay attention for all requisites for a minimum reproducible example: I had to provide files for "sky.png", "spaceship.png" and "bullet.png" in order to run your code).

And it just works.

The bullets spawn, and stay on the same line as the ship, on the botton of the screen - but since there is no code to update each bullet's `.y` position, they just stay there, instead of moving upwards. You've mentioned that this will be comming later in the tutorial you are following - so, just go for it.

Otherwise, you could for example, just change the `.y` attribute in the `update` method itself to see them moving forward. The logic for removing them from the game once they reach the top is more complex (and it would be easier if your tutorial later changes to use Pygame's sprites and groups - I hope it does).

Meanwhile, re-write your `Bullet.update` method to read this to see some action:

```
class bullet:
    
    ...

    def update(self):
        self.y -= self.bullet_speed
        self.game.screen.blit(self.bullet_img, (self.x, self.y))
```

Comment: As an extra-reference, I conducted a Space Invaders with Pygame tutorial back in PythonBrasil 2020 conference (it was held online) - the resulting code is here: https://github.com/jsbueno/invaders2020 - I had not fiddled with it since, the variable and function names are in Portuguese - but you should recognize some common logic and possibly learn from that.